# Setting up multiple highlight rules in vim

Tags: vim, highlighting

I am trying to set up rules to highlight both trailing whitespace and lines which are over a certain length by adding this to my .vimrc:

```
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=lightgray guibg=lightgray
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/

highlight OverLength ctermbg=lightgray guibg=lightgray
match OverLength /\%>80v.\+/
```

However, it only seems to pick up whichever is last. I can't find a way to get them to both work simultaneously.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way:

```
highlight EWOL ctermbg=lightgray ctermfg=black guibg=lightgray guifg=black
match EWOL /\%>20v.\+\|\s\+$/
```

Another:

```
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=lightgray ctermfg=black guibg=lightgray guifg=black
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/

highlight OverLength ctermbg=lightgray ctermfg=black guibg=lightgray guifg=black
2match OverLength /\%>80v.\+/
```

Also available: `3match`. Up to three matches can be active at a time. Or you can use [`matchadd()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#matchadd()) to create matches without limit to the quantity.

**Note:** [`3match`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#:3match) is used by matchparen, so will conflict if you use it.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`matchadd()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#matchadd()), so add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=grey guibg=grey
call matchadd('ExtraWhitespace', '\s\+$', 11)

highlight OverLength ctermbg=lightgrey guibg=lightgrey
call matchadd('OverLength', '\%>80v.\+')
```

To view all matches:

```
:echo getmatches()
```

To remove matches use [`matchdelete()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#matchdelete()).

Answer (score 1):

What about using this

> :sy[ntax] match {group-name} [{options}] [excludenl] {pattern}
>   [{options}]

```
:highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=lightgray guibg=lightgray
:syntax match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
:highlight OverLength ctermbg=lightgray guibg=lightgray
:syntax match OverLength /\%>80v.\+/
```

You can match many number of patterns using this ...